# How to use Aspose.Cells to read a specific column and row in excel? in C#

Tags: c#, excel, database, exception, error-handling

There is a web page that generates a report in Excel from time to time and I want to obtain 1 data, it is a number that changes each time the report is generated, this data is found in column I, called Quantity, and this number must be in the same row of a word, "Ready". This word is in the Status column.

I have been trying some methods but I can't do that, I can't use Oledb since it's a school laptop and I can't install Redistributable Engine Component Microsoft Access database. I tried the ExcelDataReader library, but I don't know if I'm doing things wrong. They also recommended me to use Aspose.Cells.

In my code I get an error that says that the row does not exist in the current sheet.

What is wrong with my code, and how can this be done?

```
  string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\OneDrive - me\Desktop\Data\Monitor System.xlsx"; 
            FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
            DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
            DataTable table = result.Tables[0];
            bool columnsFound = false;
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                if (!columnsFound)
                {
                    columnsFound = true;
                    continue;
                }
                string status = row["Status"].ToString();
                if (status == "Ready")
                {
                    string quantity = row["Quantity"].ToString();
                    label1.Text = quantity;
                    break;
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is relevant, but actually you were really close to the solution. Your problem was that when you create DataTable from DataSet, it doesn't give "Names" to columns from the first excel row by default. That is if I understood correctly your statement:

> this data is found in column I, called Quantity

I assume you have a first row in Excel with headers.
All you need to add is the column names and then read the appropriate values.
That is if you don't want to switch to Aspose.Cells, in which case the problem should be much easier to solve.
Here's the change to your code that will bring you data you need:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if (!columnsFound)
            {
                // set column names from the first row
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    table.Columns[i].ColumnName = row[i].ToString();
                }
                columnsFound = true;
                continue;
            }
            string status = row["Status"].ToString();
            if (status == "Ready")
            {
                string quantity = row["Quantity"].ToString();
                label1.Text = quantity;
                break;
            }
        }
```